# How to configure Proguard to remove non-trivial log messages?

Tags: android, proguard

Proguard removes *trivial* Log calls very well. (with the `assumenosideeffects` keyword)
But it handles *non-trivial* Log calls poorly.

By "Non-Trivial" I mean anything more than a single String.
For example: `Log.i(TAG,"velocity="+velocity)`". 
Proguard keeps the `new StringBuilder("velocity=")`, and also the appended variable holing the value, not much obscuring that variable. It removes only the eventual call to Log.
The strings will remain there, wasting memory, cpu cycles and also help crackers understand the code.

So to solve this, I wrap every *non-trivial* debug Log call in my app with `if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){...}`. 
But wrapping every log with `if(..){..}` is tedious and error prone.
It's certainly not DRY (Don't repeat yourself).

Is there a way to mark a method for complete removal by Proguard (or by any other means), including all calling methods?

Something like:

```
@proguard_purge
public static void vanishingDebug(String whatever) {
  Log.i(TAG,whatever);
}
```

So the method will vanish by the obfuscator, and also all calls to this method will vanish recursively as well?

***ELABORATION***

Obfuscation will optimize code and remove unused or excluded methods.
But code compilation generates extra byte codes *prior* to the method call that will be removed, and that preceding code *will* stay even after obfuscation, and leave behind code such as:

```
new StringBuilder("velocity=").append(a)
```

(Assuming `a` cannot be determined at compile time. To test, use `velocity=Math.random();`)

Which makes the obfuscated code quite trivial to understand.

To reproduce the issue, you'll need to install [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/list) to convert apk to jar, and [JAD](http://jd.benow.ca/) to convert jar to java code. 

You'll see what's really left behind, and be horrified.

***EXAMPLE***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("TAG", "Simple Comment"); // << Disappears well!

    double index = Math.random();
    index++;

    Log.i("TAG2", "log_index=" + index); // << hmm... (!)

    // class with only log calls inside
    new ReferencedClass();

    // simple method call
    MyLogger.notLog("no_log" + index); // << stays, as expected

    // simple method call with only Log call inside (aka "Log Wrapper")
    MyLogger.log("log" + index);  // << stays, as expected

    Log.i("TAG2", "This is random:" + Math.random()); // << stays, same as above

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Using this obfuscation configuration:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

It will be obfuscated to a state which can be de-compiled and de-obfuscated to this:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    double d = 1.0D + Math.random();
    new StringBuilder("log_index=").append(d).toString();
    new b();
    a.a("no_log" + d);
    new StringBuilder("log").append(d).toString();
    a.a();
    new StringBuilder("This is random:").append(Math.random()).toString();
    setContentView(2130903064);
  }
```

Comment: Have you used the assumenosideeffects keyword?

Comment: @NickT sure, this is what I meant with the *trivial* use, I edited my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is no possible way for ProGuard to know that the `StringBuilder` relates to a log he is asked to remove.

Therefore, there cannot be a ProGuard rule to remove complex Log items of the type:

```
Log.i("TAG2", "This is random:" + Math.random());
```

And it will always result in a obfuscated code with leftovers that can be decoded to:

```
new StringBuilder("This is random:").append(Math.random()).toString();
```

The only way to eliminate the leftovers is to wrap **every** non-trivial log call with:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

well as of my researches proguard cant do this at all. what you can do though, is setting up your ant build scripts.

```
<target name="-commentoutlogs">
    <replaceregexp match="(Log\..*?;\s*\n)" replace="/*\1*/" flags="gs" byline="false">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>


<target name="-uncommentlogs">
    <replaceregexp match="\/\*(Log\..*?;\s*\n)\*\/" replace="\1" flags="gs" byline="false">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

this is a simple regex-based script that you can use in your build.xml file, adding it to ant release target like this:

```
<target name="release"
            depends="-uncommentlogsbefore, -commentoutlogs, -set-release-mode, -release-obfuscation-check, -package, -post-package, -release-prompt-for-password, -release-nosign, -release-sign, -uncommentlogsafter, -post-build"
            description="Builds the application in release mode.">
</target>
```

of course you need to create target called uncommentlogsbefore aswell, with same body as uncommentlogs

this basicly puts /* before any Log. and */ after nearest );

Comment: Thanks! Problem in my case is that I'm using a 3rd party build tool (Crashlytics), which calls proguard, so I'm not sure it's possible to insert an Ant script inside their script.. But it may solve the issue for other devs, hope someone will comment here if it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rule to your proguard file in order to remove all the calls to your **debug** log printouts:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static *** d(...);  }
```

For example all lines from the following code will disappear from your obfuscated jar file:

```
String logevent = "log event";
android.util.Log.d("Tag", "This is my ");
android.util.Log.d("Tag", "This is my " + logevent);
```

P.S.
Do not forget to remove or comment out this line if you have it: **-dontoptimize**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question though, did you check the (de-)obfuscated code that indeed no StringBuilder remains at the caller side when using MyLog("text"+var)? I don't understand how a wrapper will make a difference.

Comment: The wrapper is not making the difference, you can use it on the android Log class (making an edit to the answer). Simply I was using a wrapper in my code. If you open the jar file after the obfuscation you will not see the the log line or the variable that holds the hardcoded string for the log.

Comment: The issue is not that the log call remains after obfuscation. The issue is that when using ("x="+x) in the log, javac generates a StringBuilder with "x=" and concatenates the value of x. Only then it puts the result into the log call. Proguard removes *only* the log call, but keeps the StringBuilder stuff. Did you check that specifically?

Comment: Where did you find the StringBuilder stuff when you used Log.d("tag", "x=" + var)? In the obfuscated class file? If so, I could not find anything in my obfuscated class file and I rechecked it with the above three lines of code from the answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: 4.7 here too. I've tried something similar before, but haven't tried your solution yet because I can't see how it is different. Use dex2jar to de-obfuscate and JAD to open it, and you'll probably see it too. The problem happens in the calling code

Comment: I've added an elaboration to the question, with this extra explanation of the issue.

Comment: I have to admit you scared me at first, so I rechecked my answer and I have to say I did not find any printouts or members or concats in my de-obfuscated code. I have debug printouts in my jar project and in my main apk project. For both I am using the assumenosideeffects to remove the debug prints and running dex2jar and viewing the de-obfuscated jar in jargui did not reveal any debug printout.

Comment: Michael, I'm afraid your test cannot demonstrate the problem, since ("This is my " + logevent) compiles into one simple string. Try to replace it with "This is random:" + Math.random() - and see what happens...

Comment: added an example, hope it'll be helpful